# Photoshop magic wand-like action in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

Is there a way to use a magic-wand tool (like in Photoshop) in Xcode for iPhone? What I want to do is to cut out the background of an image (a person standing in front of a white background) to make the background transparent.

Edit:
i think i was not specific enough, sorry. I would like the iPhone or iPad app to automatically remove the background of an image just taken with the camera. Thus, i can't use Photoshop for it and need a function or so to do this. I was thinking about a "flood fill" kind of solution similar to this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16405/Queue-Linear-Flood-Fill-A-Fast-Flood-Fill-Algorith

but was hoping that there is a more convenient solution especially for "cutting" out custom shaped areas of an image.

Thanks!

Comment: Xcode is not an image editor, was never meant to be. Use Photoshop proper, or another image editor.

Comment: sorry, thats not what i meant. please see my comment below..

Comment: You want the iPhone to do this programmatically?

Comment: Have you made any progress in this because I am also looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Floodfill assumes a uniform background color; on a real life photo, it won't ever be uniform. What you need is a Chromakey algorithm. See here:

[Green screen / chroma key iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561203/green-screen-chroma-key-ios)

Comment: yes, thats kind of what i am searching for but the package cost $500.. thats a bit too much for me. The solution with the video example seems interesting but i would like to really make the background transparent instead of filling it with another picture and save the result in a .png. any idea how to do it?

Comment: Google for "free chromakey" and try adapting for iOS. Or study the theory and roll your own implementation. But keep in mind - the package is pricey for a good reason. It's not a trivial thing to do. And probably will tax the iPhone's CPU considerably.